# Find all records close to particular record using Map Reduce

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce

I am trying to implement a map reduce program to find all records in a 2GB dataset which are close each other (Something like each record and its neighbors should be the output). By close to, I mean euclidean distance. In the dataset each record has an x and y coordinate. Could anyone suggest me some intuition for doing this. I know the map should emit each record and the reduce can simply run a double for loop each entry in the list inputted to it to find the neighbors, but is there a better solution to this as my implementation is horribly slow. Thanks in advance.

```
map(rid,r):
 emit(key,r)

reduce(key,lst=[r1,r2....]):
 for elm1 in lst:
  for elm2 in lst:
   if elm2 is in range of elm1:
    process(elm1,elm2)
```

The process function simply puts elm2 as a neighbor or elm1 a mongodb database. Each record in my mongodb database is structured as follows

Record 'R' | List of neighbors of Record 'R'

Answer (score 1):

You may be able to speed up your implementation by indexing the records in buckets.  Let's say all of your records are in the grid [0,100] x [0, 100].  Create 99 x-buckets [0, 1), [1, 2), ... [99, 100] and 99 y-buckets.  For a given record [x1, y1] and distance d, take the intersection of the x-buckets [x1 - d - 1] to [x1 + d + 1] and the y-buckets [y1 - d - 1] to [y1 + d + 1], and THEN test the euclidean distance of [x1, y1] against the points in the resulting set.